# Conditions to be a subspace, given a basis of the mother space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $\{u_1, \ldots , u_n, v_1, \ldots , v_k\}$ is a basis of $W$, and $U = \operatorname{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ and $V = \operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$. Does it necessarily follow that $U,V$ are subspaces of $W$?

I know that: The span of a list of vectors in $V$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all the vectors in the list. I'm not sure if this helps me here though...

I believe that $U$ and $V$ should both be subspaces of $W$, but I am having a hard time seeing why. Any help is very greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Note: I apologize for the awkward wording of the title, I am not sure how else to phrase the question..

Comment: Isn't every linear combination of basis elements of $U$ also a linear combination of basis elements of $W$, likewise for $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The span of a list of vectors in $V$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing..." etc.

That word "subspace" is meant literally.  The span of any set of vectors in a space is a subspace.